# how to keep the same button pressed style after going to another frame?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

i'm new to use actionscript and i'm creating an android application. i've got a trouble with a button. I created a button with a speaker as the default symbol. and when I press the button, the cross will appear on the button and will mute the sound. i didnt find any problem there and the button works as i want. the problem is, when i pressed the mute button and after that i'm going to another menu and back again, the mute button turns into default symbol(a speaker symbol with no cross) and the sound still silent. how can i avoid the button turn to default style after im going to another menu? thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you can fix it using multiple way , what i suggest , use preference .very fist time set default value inside preference, change that preference value while you are in another menu,while back on the same screen ,check that preference value ,is it default or changed !??put if else condition accordingly .thats it..

Comment: @Radhey can you show me an example or a link that show some solution for my problem? i still confuse right now to be honest :(

Comment: thats a logic my friend ! ,if not getting me , i can do it for you in free time.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the button state in the beginning based on the current sound state (muted / unmuted)

The button has a toggle property that indicates if it can be toggled or not. After that you could use the selected property to toggle it on or off.

```
button.toggle = true;
button.selected = true;
```

You will probably have to define the selected skins and / or icons:
http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/11/26/creating-toggle-buttons-in-flash-with-actionscript-30/

Comment: thanks for your response. i made a button similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2uXokbwUWA

Comment: but i can keep the mute image when i go to another frame. it always change to unmute image when i go back. i think the actionscript that i got on youtube is work perfectly only for 1 frame/scene. can you solve this? @Philarmon

Comment: Like I said, you have to set button's state depending on if it is muted or not when you get back. In this Youtube example, i believe just calling toggleMuteBtn(null); might help

Answer (score 0):

Use this drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeactivepressed" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitialpressed"/>
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeon"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitial"/>
</selector>
```

and set this as button background

```
 android:background="@drawable/like_button"
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all response. i already solve it. i only use a `visible` script and make it `false` on the frame that not contain the mute button, then make it `true` on the frame where the button exist. so the button image will not change to default image when im going to another frame, except i press the button again, it just hiding. i know it so amateur solution but it solve my problem really good.